# Play Framework: how to display a Future[List[String]]?

Tags: scala, http, playframework, future

I'm exploring the Play Framework and have run in to a bit of a corner.

After making an API call to Google Analytics with the WS library, I receive a `Future[Response]` object.  After digesting that Response object, I get the data I really care about, but because it's wrapped in a Future, I'm having some trouble writing it to the browser.

```
OK( gaApiString )
```

This gives me an error that reads:

> Cannot write an instance of scala.concurrent.Future[String] to HTTP
>   response. Try to define a   Writeable[scala.concurrent.Future[String]]

I'm having some trouble finding & understanding how to use a `Writable` object.  Little help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `map` the `Future` to a `Future[Result]`, passing it to `Action.async`.

```
def test = Action.async { 

    val wsResult: Future[String] = ...

    wsResult.map { gaApiString => 
        Ok(gaApiString)
    }

}
```

If `gaApiString` is actually `List[String]`, then it depends on what you want to do with it. Displaying it as a comma-separated list you could just change it to `Ok(gaApiString.mkString(","))`. The key here is mapping the `Future` to manipulate the value after it's completed.

Comment: Perfect.  All I had to do was add `.async` to my current action (eg `def updateFeed = Action.async { ...`) and everything fell right into place. Thanks.

Comment: A more concise alternative: `wsResult.map{ Ok(_)}`